# Position from acceleration, or acceleration from position, to track an object moving the speed of sound

Tags: acceleration, velocity, measurements, error-analysis

I'm working on a project that involves tracing the motion of a fast-moving object (approx the speed of sound) through a fairly defined trajectory. Would it be more accurate to measure the position of the object, then derive the speed and acceleration, or would it be more accurate to measure the acceleration and then integrate the speed and position.

Of course, in practice we might just do both concurrently, but are there any general thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I think this will likely depend more on your equipment / experimental setup: i.e. how accurately can you measure acceleration and distance?  Additionally, the purpose of these measurements are presumably important in the decision.  Finally, it's difficult to directly measure acceleration at all... it's almost always done by measuring velocity and then calculating the acceleration.

Comment: What devices do you have to measure those quantities?  I would say measuring the position would give you the least amount of drift error as that can generally be referenced to something.  Precision accerelometers can be used for very accurate short term measurements, but have a tendency to drift over long term measurements, and are usually synced with GPS occasionally if I recall correctly.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Acceleration is easier to measure on-board an object because it requires no external references.

Comment: @tmwilson26 of course, good point!  I was considering purely *external* means of measurement.  Woops!

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix To be fair to you, the OP said he is trying to "trace the motion" of the object, so he is probably doing an external measurement.  Without more information though, its hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It's unclear how we'll measure the object - at this point we're thinking we'll use accelerometers. It's probable that we might use some sort of external means to measure position as well - that might be a high speed (10K fps) camera, or perhaps something else.